# How to dry wool clothing indoors

Tags: laundry

The "official" way is to spread them on a towel. I tried that with wool socks. It takes a *long* time to dry. I also thought of using the dryer's cold setting where the dryer doesn't heat up the air, but I'm not sure that wouldn't ruin the clothing, if not immediately, maybe after multiple runs.

So, is there some lifehack to dry wool clothing indoors?

Comment: @Stephie Is the edited question better? If not, just tell me and I'll delete it. (I'm not completely clear as to what is on topic here. Some of the highest voted questions are only such because there happen to be great answers (like the fuel-tank one). But the asker doesn't know beforehand if there's some awesome lifehack they're missing or whether it's just "too bad, there's no way to achieve that.")

Comment: much better and an interesting challenge! Your initial post was more an invitation to discuss the topic of dryer use without a clear problem. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: You can hang wool socks to dry. They're not prone to stretching or to much distortion due to weight of the water when hanging. They're too light weight to matter..

Comment: @Stan I see the socks as test case to verify the principle before the OP moves to larger items like jumpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always spread my wool clothes flat over the top of my drying rack. It serves the same purpose as spreading them on a towel: they're not stretched out of proportion by gravity. You can even have other clothes hanging under the wool, but there should not be any bumps caused by clothpins.

The advantage of this compared to a towel is that air can circulate over and under the clothes, speeding up the drying process.

Comment: That. Towels are good to „wick away“ the water from wet wool which can’t be wrung, during drying they hinder evaporation and are just an extra layer that needs to dry.

Answer (score 1):

1. If it's winter, you can put your socks on the hot radiator and they will dry very fast.
2. You can use a dehumidifier. Many dehumidifiers have a setting to dry clothes. See the manual on how to use them for optimal results.

Comment: The dehumidifier sounds like a good idea. About the radiator I'm not so sure - wouldn't it ruin the clothes?

Comment: @ispiro I've been doing this for years. Especially with wool clothes like socks, underwear, towels etc there is nothing to worry about. Just make sure the radiator is clean and it doesn't have dust on it.